# Windows Server 2012 Failover Clustering and Remote procedure call failed (800706BE)

Tags: windows-server-2012, failovercluster

When i want to validate cluster configuration i get this error message:
The Remote procedure call failed.(Exception from HRESULT:0X800706be)

I disabled the Firewall and Anti-Virus but the problem still exists.
RPC Service is running and all ports like 135 are open. In windows server 2012 Remote Registry service start up is Automatic (Trigger Start), I started that service manually but nothing changed.

Comment: Include examples of the commands you are running

Comment: You should check if the clock on all cluster members, the domain controller and your management station is synchronized. Unsynchronized clocks can cause authentication failures and lead to misleading error messages from the cluster service.

Comment: Time of these servers is synchronized to domain controller.The problem is related to accessing admin shares but i dont know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to network card configuration. I disabled "Large Send Offload V2(IPv4)" and "Large Send Offload V2(IPv6)" on my network card and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Is this physical hardware or virtualized ?

If the latter check if the hard-disks are setup as fixed disk or "removable drives".
(VMWare ESX has the nasty habit of creating 2012 machines with removables.)
If the disks are removable LAN access through IPC$ and C$, D$ etc. will fail and you will need that for clustering.

For VMWare this is detailed in [KB503423](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012225). The workaround is to disable hotplugging on the virtual machine by adding an extra option to the VMX config file as described below.

```
Connect to the ESXi/ESX host or vCenter Server using the vSphere Client.
Power off the virtual machine.
Right-click the virtual machine and click Edit Settings.
Click the Options tab.
Click General > Configuration Parameters > Add Row.
Insert a new row with the name devices.hotplug and a value of false.
Power on the virtual machine.
```

Or you can set the option by adding "devices.hotplug=false" directly into the vmx file.

Comment: I use physical hardware but as you said the problem is related to accessing admin shares like c$. I checked DNS on these servers and it's working fine.I can access admin shares on these servers from other computers but not from eachother.

Comment: @Yazdkhasti Weird. On physical hardware this should work out of the box... Maybe our in-house cluster guru has some ideas, but he won't be in the office until Monday next week. I'll ask him then and update here if he comes up with something sensible.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows on both servers and the problem solved.

Comment: @Yazdkhasti Glad to hear you got it working. But not very satisfying not knowing what was the root-cause... Anyway, sometimes that's just the way it is.

Comment: I created the cluster and the cluster was working until today. I get the same error when i run validate cluster wizard. It fails at network configuration check.